# Maven credentials - how to store them securely

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, passwords

I have a maven project where my credentials are in plain text. I was wondering on how I could make this a bit more secure by not putting them there as plain text but maybe inject them in some kind of way. I was thinking something in sort of like your git credentials but don't know if this is possible. We are using Intellij and I know Intellij can store your git credentials for you but is maybe something like this also possible for your maven configuration?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For what purpose are those credentials?

Comment: authentication with nexus for our private artifacts

Answer (score 1):

Credentials for the access to nexus repository manager belong into the the `settings.xml`  in your home directory `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` and of course encrypted via `settings-security.xml`.

- https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Password_Encryption
- https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html

If you need to inject them on your ci use the appropriate mechanisms (Jenkins: config file provider plugin in relationship with credentials provider).